# Помогите составить регулярное выражение для текста

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Я совсем новичок в регулярных выражениях... Мне необходимо из следующего кода:

```
<select name="selShade" id="selShade" style="width: 100%;" 
onchange="changeProduct(this.value,'Table Lamps', 'Crystal')"> <option 
value="108085" selected="">13" x 17" 10" Natural Paper </option> 
<option value="108086">11 x 16" x 10" Silk Square</option> } </select>
```

достать только:

```
Natural Paper
```

С помощью:

```
selected="">(.*?)</option>
return $1
trim
```

Я достал только:

```
13" x 17" 10" Natural Paper
```

Как избавиться от размеров?

Заранее благодарю за ответ)

Comment: Если вы в своём решении использовали материал одного из ответов, вы можете дать ответу оценку и/или сделать его лучшим. Это в достаточной мере мотивирует и дальше отвечать на вопросы. По крайней мере, ответившему будет приятно)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте искать следующей строкой:

```
([a-zA-Z ]+)</option>
```

Если нужно только первое совпадение (как в примере), конструкция немного усложнится:

```
selected="">.*"([a-zA-Z ]+)</option>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Ваш второй вариант подходит! в чем разница return $1 и просто $1 после вашего выражения?

Comment: @MaxP Честно говоря, не знаю. Я проверял правильность на яве, т.к. в ней мне проще всего было это сделать.

Answer (score 0):

Делаем незахватывающую группу из слов, кончающихся на двойную кавычку. Остальное берем

```
selected=""\s*>(?:\s*x*\s*\w+\")+(.+)<\/option>
```

[**Демо и объяснение**](https://www.regex101.com/r/vL8iR6/1)

Comment: хоть в Вашем примере все работает, но вставляя в visual web ripper, выдает ошибку...